# rails support method for PSQL array values to ruby array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Pretty straight forward, not looking to reinvent the wheel but is there rails method that turns results from a PSQL array to a ruby array.

example

```
results = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("select array_agg(id) from users;").to_a
# => [{"array_agg"=>"{1,2,3}"}]

thing.call(results[0]["array_agg"])
# => ["1", "2","3"]
```

Comment: have you tried using `exec_query` rather than `execute`? `exec_query` appears to perform type casting based on the column type [Source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/e24fbf71fa0a10f63346b9b42604451958740844/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb#L62), whereas `execute` seems to be a bit more raw. The docs for `execute` even suggest using `exec_query` unless you specifically need a `PG::Result` object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute` returns `PG::Result` object

You need `ActiveRecord::Result` that have [`cast_values`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/04972d9b9ef60796dc8f0917817b5392d61fcf09/activerecord/lib/active_record/result.rb#L104-L128) method (it uses `deserialize` under the hood)

`exec_query` does this job

```rb
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query("select array_agg(id) from users;").cast_values

# => [[1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: will cast_values guarantee the same order as the columns?

Comment: The order should be the same